# How to limit window proportions on windows resize in VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player, window

To illustrate what I want, here is a gif from `MPC-HC` with this options enabled:

[image http://i.minus.com/ibmdKlQeyKn614.gif](http://i.minus.com/ibmdKlQeyKn614.gif)

And here is gif when resizing window from VLC:

[image http://i.minus.com/ibgUWABnnD2dZe.gif](http://i.minus.com/ibgUWABnnD2dZe.gif)

How can I limit window proportions on window resize in VLC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't unless there is a plug in. The developers are not adapt enough to impliment this -- which has been requested since 2005 -- or a borderless window feature as in other players (mpc, mpc-hc, mpv, etc).